# Difference between creating a scope using Autofac LifeTimeScope and Asp.net Core DI Extension IServiceScopeFactory

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm developing an application in **Asp.net Core** using the **Autofac** as the default DI and in my integration tests I require some services which before installing 
 the Autofac I was injecting by creating a `IServiceScopeFactory` and then calling the method `CreateScope()` to be able to get the services needed, just like the code below:

```
public void ExampleOfAspNetServiceScope(){    
     var scopeFactory = _testServer.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

     using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope()){
         var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISomeService>();
         // Some stuff...
     }
}
```

---

After installing the Autofac into my application I've found in the documentation the interface ILifeTimeScope and now my code could be rewriten as follows:

```
public void ExampleOfAutofacScope(){    
     var lifetimeScope = _testServer.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILifetimeScope>();

     using (var scope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope()){
         var service = scope.Resolve<ISomeService>();
         // Some stuff...
     }
}
```

I did integration tests with both and it seems they behave equally. So, I was wondering what are the differences between the two approaches.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the same thing, just using the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection abstractions instead of using Autofac directly.

[I'd recommend looking at the actual code in Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection for more concrete clarity.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) There's not actually much to it and you can see for yourself precisely how it works.

Comment: So, should I always inject an IServiceProvider instead of ILifetimeScope when I need to resolve some dependencies by hand?

Comment: That is 100% up to you.

Comment: Could you look at my answer below?  I know you are a developer for Autofac and I'd like to know if this is an expected behavior or if it is a bug...

Comment: I think it's correct but it's a confusing read and, honestly, I'm in Disneyland right now and trying to stay pretty offline. Sorry I can't do more.

Comment: oups, sorry for the that!

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly the same thing... as long as you don't override registrations in child scopes.  IServiceProvider.CreateScope will create a new scope from the root one whereever the current IServiceProvider is.  ILifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope will create a child scope of the current one.  Here is the code to illustrate that (.Net 6 and Autofac 6.4):

```
var root = ((LifetimeScope)lifetimeScope).RootLifetimeScope;

using var ls1 = root.BeginLifetimeScope();
using var ls2 = ls1.BeginLifetimeScope();

var spRoot = root.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
using var sp1 = spRoot.CreateScope();
using var sp2 = sp1.ServiceProvider.CreateScope();

bool isLs1ChildOfRoot = ((LifetimeScope)ls1).ParentLifetimeScope == root; //true
bool isSp1ChildOfRoot = ((LifetimeScope)((AutofacServiceProvider)sp1.ServiceProvider)
    .LifetimeScope).ParentLifetimeScope == root; //true

bool isLs2ChildOfRoot = ((LifetimeScope)ls2).ParentLifetimeScope == root; //false
bool isLs2ChildOfLs1 = ((LifetimeScope)ls2).ParentLifetimeScope == ls1; //true
bool isSp2ChildOfRoot = ((LifetimeScope)((AutofacServiceProvider)sp2.ServiceProvider)
    .LifetimeScope).ParentLifetimeScope == root; //true

bool sp1EqualsSp2 = sp1 == sp2; //false
```

For the most part, both will act the same way since scoped registrations will honnor the new scope and create a new instance in the child scope of another child scope.  Problems arise when you use advanced features of autofac like overriding registrations or adding registrations in a child scope: If you create a new scope with IServiceProvider, you will lose those registrations because the new scope will be a child of root instead of the scope with the custom registrations.